# useDebugValue not Displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just tried to use the [useDebugValue Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usedebugvalue). I created the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useDebugValue, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true);

  useDebugValue(isOnline ? "Online" : "Offline");

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIsOnline(isOnline => !isOnline);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">Hello World: {"" + isOnline}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

My code works fine: each second isOnline is modified. But where do I see the debugValue? My Console looks like the following

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it inside a custom hook:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function useFriendStatus() {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIsOnline(isOnline => !isOnline);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
  // Show a label in DevTools next to this Hook
  // e.g. "FriendStatus: Online"
  React.useDebugValue(isOnline ? "Online" : "Offline");

  return isOnline;
}

export default function App() {
  const isOnline = useFriendStatus();

  React.useDebugValue(isOnline ? "Online" : "Offline");

  return <div className="App">Hello World: {"" + isOnline}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit proud-currying-nrcyr]

[Demo](https://nrcyr.csb.app/)